# How to sort a matrix in a row-wise manner in java

Tags: java, matrix, user-input

I've been trying to sort the elements of my matrix in a row-wise manner. But when I try to sort them out I end up with the error `error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[][]`. And for some reason I can't find a way to get rid of the error.

Below is the code that I made.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class arrayinput2{
    
    static void sortByRow(int m[][], int n){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            Arrays.sort(m[i]);
    }
    
    static void transpose(int m[][], int n){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                {
                int temp=m[i][j];
                m[i][j]=m[j][i];
                m[j][i]=temp;
                }
    }
    
    static void sortMatRowAndColWise(int m[][],int n)
    {
        sortByRow(m, n);
        transpose(m, n);
        sortByRow(m, n);
        transpose(m, n);
    }
    
    static void printMat(int m[][], int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    public  static void main(String args[]){
        int m,n,i,j;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
        m = sc.nextInt();
        n = m;
        
        int array[][] = new int[m][n];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array: ");
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        array[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        

        System.out.println("Elements of the array are: ");
        printMat(m, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: You're not calling `sortMatRowAndColWise()` at all in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

You've used inconsistent naming conventions.

In some methods `m` as a parameter refers to a 2D array.

In your `main()`, though, you've declared `m` as an `int`!

Change:

```
printMat(m, n);
```

To:

```
printMat(array, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

WHY DOES THIS HAPPENED

1- m is an integer type in your main method and keeps the number of rows.

2- The method printMat(int m[][],int n) takes a 2D array and an integer.

3- When you run printMat(m,n) you try to put an integer to a 2D array.(Consider that 'm' in printMat(int m[][],int n) and 'm' in int m; are not the same.)

WHAT SHOULD YOU DO

You should write printMat(array,n) instead print(m,n).